# Compound interest vs cumulative growth rate

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My friend gave me the following problem. Imagine you made \$10 in
January. You ended up making \$100 by the end of December. What would
the growth rate have to be on the income if you were to make \$100 cumulative
in 12 months? His answer was:
$$
10+10(1+r)+10(1+r)^{2}+...=100
$$
and then solve for $r.$ Mine was to use the compound interest formula:
$$
10\left(1+r\right)^{12}=100
$$
What is the conceptual difference between the two formulas? In both
cases, the 10 grows to 100. I undersand what is going on mathematically here, but aren't the two conceptually super related? If not, where is the key difference?

Answer (score 1):

In his formula if the ... goes on forever, it will converge only for negative r.  Yours is the formula for **monthly** compounding, which is not specified.